# javascript and blogger help needed

Tags: javascript, web, popup, blogger, ads

I'm using this script for ads on many of my websites:

[image]

But when I add this to my template head section on blogspot it gets changed to:

[image]

I'm using this code from popads.net and I have no problems with this on any of my other websites. this is the first time I'm using a blog from blogspot.com with popads.

How can I fix this?

Comment: how are you including the script on your website? It looks like it is being HTML escaped.

Comment: Are you getting the same encoding problems with " characters too?

Comment: im simply copying the code before the </head> by editing the template within blogger.com

Comment: no,, characters work fine,

Comment: Have you tried specifying encoding: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`? I've also seen `<script language='javascript'>` used on a previous stack question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31885/blogger-how-to-add-scripts-to-blog

Comment: yes tried them both, didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose your javascript code in //

Your code would then look like

```
    // <![CDATA[
    _pop.push('siteId', 3959]);
    .
    .
    .
    // ]]>
```

Lines between //  are considered as comments by the XML parser, thereby preventing the change from ' to '